# Regex for URL matching

Tags: regex

I want to match below two URLs.

```
1. /,a=e[o],e[o]=function(){s=arguments},i.always(function(){e[o]=a,n[o]&&(n.jsonpcallback=r.jsonpcallback,fn.push(o)),s&&x.isfunction(a)&&a(s[0]),s=a=t}),

2. /,a[f]=function(){h=arguments},e.always(function(){a[f]=g,c[f]&&(c.jsonpcallback=d.jsonpcallback,ce.push(f)),h&&p.isfunction(g)&&g(h[0]),h=g=b}),
```

For that regex is :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9:\/\.,\[\]\=\(\) \{\}\=\&]{0,500}$
```

But above mention Reg-ex match with :

https://www.test.com/test/test/test.php

I Want to write reg-ex where all special character like []{}()&,. In above two URL are compulsory but if this all mention special character is not available then reg-ex should not match.

Comment: Not sure why people have downvoted this, I know the language issues are a little difficult to work with, but is contains a clear requirement and shows attempted efforts, so it's a good question in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

```
^(?=.*\[)(?=.*])(?=.*\{)(?=.*})(?=.*\()(?=.*\))(?=.*&)(?=.*,)(?=.*\.)[a-zA-Z0-9:\/\.,\[\]\=\(\) \{\}\=\&]{0,500}$
```

---

**Longer Answer**

You can use a positive lookahead to ensure the result contains a set of characters.

For example, add this to the start:

```
(?=.*\[)
```

And it will only match results that contain an opening square bracket `[`

You can do this for each of the special characters that you need to ensure are present.

For example, if you want to ensure it contains **all** of the characters `[]{}()&,.` then you would add this at the start:

```
(?=.*\[)(?=.*\])(?=.*\{)(?=.*\})(?=.*\()(?=.*\))(?=.*\&)(?=.*\,)(?=.*\.)
```

Just be sure to escape the relevant characters depending on your programming language and type of regex